# How to fetch checkbox value in Angular Reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I am learning Angular now. I am making a Reactive Form which has a group of checkboxes. I have created those checkboxes using Angular Material. So far after googling for the whole day I wasn't able to come up with a solution which tells me to get the checkbox checked value in `FormGroup` in TS file. I am attaching the code herewith.

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formdata">
   <label>Vehicles</label><br>
   <mat-radio-group>
      <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let v of Vehicles" formControlName="vehicles" [value]="v.value">{{ v.option }}</mat-checkbox>
   </mat-radio-group>
</form>
{{ formdata.value | json }}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

export interface model
{
  value: string; //Store value for the option
  option: string; //Stores option to be displayed
}

export class FormComponent implements OnInit{
    Vehicles: model[] = [{value: '2 wheelers', option: '2 wheelers'}, {value: '4 wheelers', option: '4 wheelers'}];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
formdata = this.fb.group({
    vehicles: []
});
}
```

I am getting the output as ``` true or false`` but I want the output as ```2 or 4 or 2,4```.

Please help me out.

Comment: are you asking about **mat-radio-button** ? https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

Comment: I see you want checkboxes - This demo is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stszta

Comment: @Eliseo I'm implementing mat-checkbox only the only reason of writing mat-radio-group is just to group them in line

Comment: @AvishekDattaRay, for me it's not natural, but you can use the [checked] property and the (change) event to change the value of the form, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use the mat-checkbox alone. Remember, the FormGroup exist even you has no input. So you can use [checked] and (change) to change the value of the formControl.

```
<form [formGroup]="formdata">
   <label>Vehicles</label><br>
   <mat-radio-group>
      <mat-checkbox  
      (change)="formdata.get('vehicles').setValue($event.checked?2:null)"
      [checked]="formdata.value.vehicles==2" >2 Wheelers</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox 
      [checked]="formdata.value.vehicles==4"
      (change)="formdata.get('vehicles').setValue($event.checked?4:null)"

      >4 Wheelers</mat-checkbox>
   </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyxvbk?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html)

**Update** really I don't understand the question, The question was create a serie of checkbox and return an array. The idea it's the same, we has an array (in this case of object) and a FormControl. we can use the own array of objects

So,

```
<form [formGroup]="formdata">
   <label>Vehicles</label><br>
   <mat-radio-group>
      <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let v of Vehicles" 
         [checked]="v.active" 
         (change)="v.active=$event.checked;setVehicles()">
          {{ v.option }}
       </mat-checkbox>
   </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

And the function "setVehicles" is the function that give value to the form. How? filter the array Vehicles and map to the value

```
setVehicles()
  {
    this.formdata.get('vehicles').setValue(
       this.Vehicles.filter(x=>x.active) //first filter
       .map(x=>x.value)  //second map to get only the "value"
    )
  }
```

See the [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyxvbk-5cgqpf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts)

NOTE: I use the same array of objects and add a property "active" "on fly" (this is because I defined the array as :any[])

NOTE2: In this case I give value to the formControl each time you change any check-box, this action can be used only when we submit the form

Comment: ok I understood this but I think it makes look like a radio button. I want checkbox and in checkbox more than 1 value can also return

Comment: and i've updated my code also that time I wasn't using ```FormBuilder``` and the checkboxes were static . This time I've iterated through loop.

Comment: sorry, I've not understand you, you want some like a multi-select but with checkbox. I update the answer.