# Assign the value of a checkbox to a FormControlName (Angular)

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a reactive form and want to take the value of a checkbox (not 'true' or 'false') and assign it to a formControlName (selectedSizeValueControl).

I have try some method but they do not work for me.

Can anyone please help?

The code:

```
    <form [formGroup]="variantForm" (ngSubmit) = "submit()">
    
      <mat-checkbox value="{{selectedSizeValue}}" formControlName = "selectedSizeValueControl"  >{{selectedSizeValue}}</mat-checkbox>
     
      <mat-radio-button value="{{sale_preis.value}}"><input type="text" #sale_preis formControlName ="sale_preis"></mat-radio-button>
    
      <button >save</button>
    </form>
```

component.ts

```
selectedSizeValues: string;

variantForm = new FormGroup({
    selectedSizeValueControl: new FormControl(),
    sale_preis: new FormControl()  });

submit(){
    console.log(this.variantForm.value);

  }
```

selectedSizeValueControl only takes TRUE or FALSE, I want it take the value of selectedSizeValue ( for ex: a string)

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you share your component.ts code?

Comment: Hi @DevangPatel: I have added the component.ts.

Comment: What's `selectedSizeValue`? A checkbox can only be checked or unchecked, what kind of value are you trying to store in `selectedSizeValueControl`?

Comment: some like this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937336/how-to-fetch-checkbox-value-in-angular-reactive-form/60958395#60958395 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded with this.

- Do not use formControlName along with value
- Use the property bidning *[value]="selectedSizeValue"*  instead of *value = {{selectedSizeValue}}*
- I take the value from the checkbox and assign it to the *formControlName* through a function inside component.ts. That's it.

```
<form [formGroup]="variantForm" (ngSubmit) = "submit()">
    
      <input type="checkbox" [value]="selectedSizeValue" (change)="GetStats($event)" >

      <mat-radio-button value="{{sale_preis.value}}"><input type="text" #sale_preis formControlName ="sale_preis"></mat-radio-button>
    
      <button >save</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
selectedSizeValues: string;

test: string ='';

variantForm = new FormGroup({
    selectedSizeValueControl: new FormControl(),
    sale_preis: new FormControl()  });

submit(){
       this.variantForm.value.selectedSizeValueControl = this.test;
  }
GetStats(event: Event) {
    console.log(event);
    // @ts-ignore
    this.test = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.test);
  }
```

Comment: you need also check if event.target.value is false to **not assing** the value, futhermore, you need also use a setValue to give value to the FormControl

Answer (score 1):

`mat-checkbox` can only handle true or false and will not take a string. Change the element to an `input` or change the type of `selectedSizeValues` to be a boolean.